# Problems assigning char string to char array

Tags: string, dev-c++, arrays, incompatibletypeerror

I have already read all prior answers regarding my problem. However, I'm not a very bright coder to am unable to grasp it. Could someone please look into my problem.

I am trying to write a CSV file using entries from a 2D array. string.h has already been included in main().

```
void create_marks_csv(int rout[][20],float p[][20],float c[][20],int n)
{
    system("cls");
    char str1[100],str2[100],str3[100];
    printf("\nEnter filename for routing matrix: ");
    gets(str1);
    printf("\n Creating %s.csv file",str1);
    FILE *fp;
    int i,j;
    str1=strcat(str1,".csv");
    str1=strcat("C:\\Users\\Neil\\Documents\\Trust CSV Logs\\",str1) ;
    fp=fopen(str1,"w+");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            if(i==j)
                fprintf(fp,"X");
            else
                fprintf(fp,"%d",rout[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(fp,"\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\nFile created: %s",str1);
    system("cls");
}
```

The warnings and errors are as follows:

```
5   20  C:\Users\Neil\Documents\main.c  [Warning] extra tokens at end of #include directive [enabled by default]
C:\Users\Neil\Documents\main.c  In function 'create_marks_csv':
168   6 C:\Users\Neil\Documents\main.c  [Error] incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[100]' from type 'char *'
169   6 C:\Users\Neil\Documents\main.c  [Error] incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[100]' from type 'char *'
28      C:\Users\Neil\Documents\Makefile.win    recipe for target 'main.o' failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you write `str1 =`, you are telling the compiler to change `str1` so that it points to whatever location in memory is found on the right-hand side of the `=` sign.  But you declared `char str1[100]`, which means that `str1`, interpreted as a pointer, can only point to the start of the block of 100 characters at the location where this declaration allocated them.  So it makes no sense to write `str1 =`.

Passing a C string constant as the first argument of `strcat` is likely to be a disaster, although the compiler seems not to mind.  The first argument of `strcat` should be a character buffer big enough to hold the results of the concatenation.  In order to concatenate something onto the end of a constant string, you can allocate a buffer big enough, then copy the constant string to it, then call `strcat`.

In general you can probably do whatever you need to do without using the return value of `strcat`, that is, no need to ever write `strcat` on the right-hand side of `=`.

It is advisable to use `fgets` instead of `gets` because then you can protect against the possibility that you will get too much input to fit in your allocated character buffer.  If you allocate 100 characters in your largest buffer, you can only afford to accept 95 characters minus the length of the string `"C:\\Users\\Neil\\Documents\\Trust CSV Logs\\"`. (The other 5 characters are required to hold the string `".csv"` and the terminating null character).

I saw also that you declare `str2` and `str3` but I didn't see where you used either of them.  It looks like you don't need both of them, but you might find it convenient to use `str2` as the buffer for your last concatenation of strings.